# changing timebase of mkv file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to change the tbn of a mkv file.

Here is the command I typed.

> ffmpeg -i a.mkv -video_track_timescale 90000 -c copy a_9ktbn.mkv

But timebase didn't change

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'a.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:41.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4647 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.640000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.600000000
Output #0, matroska, to 'a_9ktbn.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.640000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.600000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

Below is the result of ffprobe

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'a_9ktbn.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:41.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4647 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.639000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.600000000
```

tbn didn't change.

Also I found it weird that log of the ffmpeg command says tbc of output file is 1k, Whereas ffprobe say it is 120.

I tried same thing on a ts file, It didn't worked too.

Is it impossible to change the tbn of a mkv(+ts) file?

Answer (score 1):

Although the Matroska format supports up to nanosecond precision timestamps, currently ffmpeg only seems to support milisecond timestamps, which is the default value. (There is [a patch](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2021-May/280460.html) to fix this, but it doesn't appear to be merged)

Instead of ffmpeg, you can use the `mkvmerge` parameter `--timestamp-scale` to change the time base as nanoseconds. For example, for a tbn of 90000, use `--timestamp-scale 11111`, since 1000000ns / 90000 = 11111.111111ns. Note however that it's impossible to get exact precision timestamps with the mkv format when you have a timebase that is a multiple of 3 since you will have repeating decimals, but all timestamps are rounded to nanoseconds.

See https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html for details about `mkvmerge` usage

See also `TimestampScale` in https://www.matroska.org/technical/notes.html about the format